# Failing JSON Deserialization in VS2012 C#

Tags: c#, json, datacontractserializer, json-deserialization

Using VS 2012 with C#, I am trying to deserialize json response data from a web site's api but i'm getting null values after serialization.  I've tried several difference deserialization methods and they all return null values.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The following are the details:

**Sample JSON response data:**

```
{"response":{"metaInfo":{"timestamp":"2015-07-06T20:44:51Z","mapVersion":"8.30.58.159","moduleVersion":"7.2.58.0-1179","interfaceVersion":"2.6.13"},"route":[{"routeId":"AHAACAAAAB4AAAA6AAAAnwAAAJUAAAB42mOYysDAxMQABM6p7Z2hoaGpDFCQmBQqZsdib8Pw/z9E4MN+BiTABcThf3LOMDHk1U9A0ZgC1GjCiVdj3cKXQYxAi+GC/3s/ZruBJRvYgJSAHgBjgBtIVTckbg==","mode":{"type":"fastest","transportModes":["car"],"trafficMode":"enabled","feature":[]},"leg":[{"length":4014,"travelTime":612}]}],"language":"en-us"}}
```

**JSON Data class:**

I initially used json2csharp.com conversion to build the class structure from the above json text. I renamed the generated class name to JSONResponseData.  Later I added all the [DataMember] entries after seeing an MSDN example having this notation.  But with or without [DataMember] there was no difference in the returned deserialized values.  There was also no difference with changing the generated json class name.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace JsonApiClient
{
/// <summary>
/// Class to represent the JSONResponseData
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class JSONResponseData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string mapVersion { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string moduleVersion { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string interfaceVersion { get; set; }
}

public class Mode
{
    [DataMember]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> transportModes { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string trafficMode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<object> feature { get; set; }
}

public class Leg
{
    [DataMember]
    public int length { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int travelTime { get; set; }
}

public class Route
{
    [DataMember]
    public string routeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Mode mode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Leg> leg { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    [DataMember]
    public JSONResponseData metaInfo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Route> route { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string language { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Main Program:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace JsonApiClient
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string baseUrl = "http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id={0}&app_code={1}&waypoint0={2}&waypoint1={3}&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&avoidseasonalclosures=true&metricsystem=imperial&routeattributes=none,lg,ri&legattributes=none,le,tt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String appid = "DemoAppId01082013GAL";
            String appcode = "AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg";
            String waypoint0 = "geo!52.5,13.4";
            String waypoint1 = "geo!52.5,13.45";

            // Customize URL according to geo location parameters
            String url = string.Format(baseUrl, appid, appcode, waypoint0, waypoint1);

            // Syncronous Consumption
            var syncClient = new WebClient();
            var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

            // visual display of content
            Console.WriteLine(content);

            //
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JSONResponseData));
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content)))
            {
                // deserialize the JSON object using the JSONResponseData type.
                var responseData = (JSONResponseData)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

                // Set breakpoint here to monitor responseData value
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong type i.e. JSONResponseData. Use RootObject as type in DataContractSerializer and cast the result in RootObject.

Here's the updated code. I have included the JSON.Net serialization as well which is way much faster and better than using DataContractSerializer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String appid = "DemoAppId01082013GAL";
    String appcode = "AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg";
    String waypoint0 = "geo!52.5,13.4";
    String waypoint1 = "geo!52.5,13.45";

    // Customize URL according to geo location parameters
    String url = string.Format(baseUrl, appid, appcode, waypoint0, waypoint1);

    // Syncronous Consumption
    var syncClient = new WebClient();
    var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

    // Using JSON.NET to deserialize object
     var responseDataSerialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

    // visual display of content
    Console.WriteLine(content);

    // Here's using DataContractSerializer
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content)))
    {
        // deserialize the JSON object using the JSONResponseData type.
        var responseData = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

        // Set breakpoint here to monitor responseData value
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful insight!  This solved my issue!

Comment: You can mark this as answer. It would help other users as well.